# How to List Iceberg Tables in a Catalog

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue, apache-iceberg

I'm trying to just list all tables in my Iceberg-enabled catalog.

Falling back to Spark-Sql works

```
spark.sql(s"USE ${catalogName}.${databaseName}")
val tables = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES")
```

Is it possible to accomplish the same with meta classes like `spark.catalog`, specific `SparkSessionCatalog().listTables(catalogName, databaseName)`, or the generic `BaseMetastoreCatalog().listTables(Namespace.of(catalogName))`

I have not had much luck with any. I have an environment fully configured to use Iceberg for `catalogName`. I can read/write to tables, but general data catalog inspection is beyond me.